# Kdevelop with Python / C++ : no output in debug mode

Tags: python, c++, debugging, output, kdevelop

I'm new to Kdevelop, and I'm bumping into a problem when running in debug mode :

I have the simplest possible code , that just prints :

```
print "Hello World! \n"
print "How are you doing World ?\n"
print "Bye World! \n"
```

When using Execute , everything works fine, I get the expected ouput.
However, in Execute I cannot have any breakpoints (or any debug feature for that matter).

When using Debug mode, I have breakpoints and all the usefull things, but I don't have any output in the Output View Tool Bar.

A sort-of-similar behavior happens when using Kdevelop for C++ :

In debug mode nothing is printed until you print a "\n" (seems to cause some sort of flush).

reference :
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=100980

I cannot help to think that these two behaviors are somehow related, so an answer for why in C++ "\n" causes a flush for Kdevelop (and hopefully how to duplicate this in python) might shift me into the right direction.

Things I've tried :

- sys.stdout.flush(); - no effect
- using -u argument in the Behavior Script Application Configuration - no effect
- using python -u as Interpreter Command in the Script Application Conf - "Sorry, debugging is only supported for Python 2.x application"...so parameter shouldn't be here :)

So, any takes on how to print in the debug output for KDevelop when running Python scripts ?

Comment: same problem i have... did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Enable `external terminal` in launch configuration and build the project again. Finally, start the debugger and the output terminal will open in a new window.